# Apple ID Moving country

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I've moved from Ireland to the UK and am now getting paid in GBP, so I decided i'd move my Apple ID to the UK store (even though I like the Irish top app charts more)
I found that after I move my account to UK and add a UK Card all my previous app purchases on the Mac App store and on the iOS App store are no longer in my 'Purchased' tab.
This is really annoying, I believe I can download any of the old apps i've purchased and a message pops up explaining that I can re download for free, but it's really not a good solution.
Anyone know what else won't work correctly now? will iCloud backups or iMessage mess up too?
This sucks - any fix to this ridiculous problem?

How can apple be so sloppy on this?

Comment: It is for your protection. Just call them and they will fix it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Unfortunately they cannot, I contacted iTunes support (multiple times with multiple people) and they all said it's not possible to change.

Comment: Things can get even more ridiculous. I'm a Finnish person living in Chile temporarily. As a temporary resident, I can't get a Chilean credit card, and I don't have a Finnish address any longer. As a result, I can't set the country of my Apple ID at all, because my credit cards and billing address are from different countries. I probably can't buy anything from App Store or iTunes Store or even upgrade to Mountain Lion before I move to another country in a couple of years.

Comment: That is ridiculous!

Comment: What would you like them to do? they can not just transfer "your" credits to a new account. Almost like changing from Visa to AMEX :). Did you not say you just moved from Ireland to UK ? how did you end up in Chile. As for the address, it is not the one you are living at, it is the one registered with the credit card.

Comment: Hey Buscar, that was a different person saying they lived in Chile (not me) :)

Comment: And I do expect them to move my purchase history! Especially for apps that are available on both stores. 1) What happend to it just works!! and 2) I've spent about 20K on this stuff!

Comment: @Buscar웃 As I said, I don't have a Finnish address any longer, so my Finnish credit cards are registered to my Chilean address. Anyway, my guess is that Apple considers people moving to new country to be such a marginal group that it's not worth the effort to make things work for them.

Comment: @JouniSirén seems to be that way buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I had to call Apple senior support to fix this.

Comment: You had to? Calling is the only way to fix this?

Comment: Yeah and they didn't really fix it, I now get updates but my 'purchased tab' doesn't show my Irish purchases, I can download them all for free (as I come across them/need them) but it's still annoying. When I move home to Ireland, apparently all I buy here will be the same, still free to download but NOT show in my purchased tab.